# Is there a term for this piece of hair?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, image-identification

So I usually look at this part and my side burns to tell if I need a hair cut. The part I refer to is probably the start of a pony tail (I'm a guy btw). This is only on the back of the head, but not all people get this. Here is an image that shows what I'm referring to.

[image]

Original [Link](https://pamseattle.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/curly-hair-2.jpg)

Clearly at the bottom of his hair, there is a small pony tail-like hair piece. Is there a term for this?

Comment: I think you're talking about a mullet.

Comment: I just checked, it is not a mullet. I'm talking about just the small beginning of a pony tail part, not the hair style.

Comment: Sure looks like the beginnings of a mullet to me.

Comment: @HotLicks- I think a mullet requires trimming on the front and sides as well.

Comment: Closer to a rat tail than a mullet.

Comment: @HotLicks  the OP's link is definitely not a mullet, please see [Rod Stewart and Ron Wood](https://www.google.it/search?q=Rod+Stewart+mullet&biw=1366&bih=641&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCAQsARqFQoTCIKhweGb5McCFcteFAodJCMJsg#tbm=isch&q=Rod+Stewart+Ron+Wood+mullet) for two prime examples of mullets. :)

Comment: The OP wants to know the "word", and there might be a specific term among hairdressers, hence the "terminology" tag. The image identification tag could easily be answered with: It's the back of a man's head.

Comment: I was born with one as well. My grandmother, from Northern Italy, called it a "coppine". I cannot find this word in the Italian dictionary, so I assume it is from the provincial dialect of the area. There is an Italian superstition related to the coppine. She told my mother it meant that her next child would be female, which indeed did happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **rat-tail** or **rattail** is the term for a small, thin piece of hair protruding from the base of otherwise short hair. These are often braided and can be quite long, but they aren't always. See [here](http://www.trendhunter.com/trends/ratty-hairstyles-rattail) for some examples of short, unbraided styles still deemed rat-tails (as well examples of their longer and braided cousins).

Comment: "I worked six months for that son of a gun; Jess Harold was his name

Six -foot seven in his stocking feet, as tall as any crane.

His hair hung down in rattails o'er his long and lantern jaw

A photograph of all the gents in the state of Arkansas.

Answer (score 3):

The expression **tapered nape area** seems to fit. The nape (the back of the neck)  hairline is different for everyone of us. In the OP's case his nape hairline tapers towards the centre creating a mini-ponytail.

[There are three basic styles of rear hairline](https://meandrichard.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/richard-armitages-rear-hairline-or-looking-at-the-wrong-things/): Block, round, and tapered.

[image]

Here is a woman's hairstyle seen from behind, where the nape hairline is deliberately cut into a triangular shape

[image]

> **Napes** (predominantly super-short) are neatly outlined to follow the natural contours of the hairline, beneath either distinctive “weight-lines” of the blunt cut bob, or graduated/ tapered into the soft, feminine curve of the lower neck.
> Source: [Hair Xstatic](http://www.hairxstatic.com/styles/sbb.php?index=3)

Different types of nape hairlines

> Nape hairline. This is the hairline at the back of the neck. Care is needed particularly when designing shorter styles because this hairline can grow into **a point at the centre of the nape**, or into two points, or into three, or sometimes can grow straight across the nape.
>
> Source: [Hairdressing world.com](http://hairdressingworld.com/)

Image of a boy's [nape hairline](http://cdn2.stocksy.com/a/cJP000/z0/97316.jpg) which has a natural point in the centre.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it a prospective/potential/upcoming **pig-tail**.

> - **prospective** - "likely to be or become something specified in the future"
> - **potential** - "capable of becoming real"
> - **upcoming** - "happening or appearing soon"

Comment: A pig tail is on the side of the head and usually comes in pairs; a pony tail is on the back.

Comment: @jim That is subjective to cultural boundaries. Back in the 80's UK boys referred to this style as a pigtail.

Comment: Nelson's sailors wore pigtails, at the back of the head.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it the **nip** of hair on the nape of your neck. I believe this is caused by your cowlicks but there may be a more applicable term for the cause of this pattern.

> After an amazing dinner you two made your way to the dance floor, your fingers intertwined and your hand resting on the small of her back while her hand went on the back of your neck, playing with the nip of hair there. –[instagram.com](https://instagram.com/p/5-9TreiMCh/)

Comment: It would have to use the full phrase _"the nip of hair on the nape of your neck"_. I believe "nip" would just refer to a small bundle of hair.

Comment: Also, don't Google _"nip of hair"_ without the quotes...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could describe it as a plain ***small [queue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(hairstyle))***:

> - *The queue or cue is a hairstyle, frequently used in reference to 
>     men*, in which the hair is worn long and gathered up into a ponytail, often braided. It was worn traditionally by the Manchu people of Manchuria and certain Native American groups.

Wikipedia)